# Is microcontroller development kit can be used for programming any number of microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller

I am a non technical person and trying hands on making devices. i have one stupid question. I want to know, is micro-controller development kit can program unlimited microcontrollers (programming will be same for all micro-controller) or we need separate micro controller development kit and separate microcontroller in every device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each type of micro-controller will have its own development kit. That kit works with all the  same or similar micro-controllers. But, you will need separate micro-controller for each device.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read the license for the tool when you buy it, some yes, some no.  Often you dont use the developers kit to program the parts, you use a programming tool (which may or may not be part of the same kit) for production.   Some tools will program different vendors parts or all the parts within a vendors product list, but in general that is not the case.  depending on the device there are a lot of free tools (avrdude for example) that dont have restrictions, but it is vendor/chip specific as to what tool will work for the microcontroller in question.

Simply read the docs on the tool you are interested in to see what it does and doesnt support, read the license agreement to see if there is a limit on the number of devices per software license.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of coffeemakers and washing machines with a microcontroller in them. And clearly the manufacturers of those don't buy microcontroller dev kits by the billions. That would be unaffordable.